# python: `len` vs `sum` of a filtered list

Tags: python, python-3.x

We compare counting elements in an list that satisfy a constraint (the constraint in the examples below test if the element is odd).

In python3, `len` is significantly faster than `sum`:

```sh
$ python3 -m timeit -s 'X = list(range(1000))' 'len([1 for x in X if x % 2])'
5000 loops, best of 5: 41.4 usec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit -s 'X = list(range(1000))' 'sum(1 for x in X if x % 2)'
5000 loops, best of 5: 52.7 usec per loop
```

In python2, `len` is only about six or seven percent faster than `sum`:

```sh
$ python2 -m timeit -r 5 -s 'X = list(range(1000))' 'len([1 for x in X if x % 2])'
10000 loops, best of 5: 49 usec per loop
$ python2 -m timeit -r 5 -s 'X = list(range(1000))' 'sum(1 for x in X if x % 2)'
10000 loops, best of 5: 52.5 usec per loop
```

1. In python3, why the large difference?
2. python2 `len` is significantly slower than `python3`.  Is this to be expected?  Why or why not?
3. Since `sum` is using a generator (in both py2 and py3), does it use less space than `len`?

Update:
Following @donkopotamus comment, I removed the `x % 2` condition.  Now, the two `len`s are about the same.  But `sum` in py3.7.3 is a lot slower than py2.7.16.

```sh
$ python2 -m timeit -r 5 -s 'X = list(range(1000))' 'len([1 for x in X])'
10000 loops, best of 5: 21.7 usec per loop
$ python2 -m timeit -r 5 -s 'X = list(range(1000))' 'sum(1 for x in X)'
10000 loops, best of 5: 30.5 usec per loop

$ python3 -m timeit -s 'X = list(range(1000))' 'len([1 for x in X])'
10000 loops, best of 5: 21.8 usec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit -s 'X = list(range(1000))' 'sum(1 for x in X)'
5000 loops, best of 5: 40.8 usec per loop
```

py versions: 2.7.16 and 3.7.3

Comment: The answers to both 1. and 2. have **nothing to do with `len`** and everything to do with the fact that evaluating the **list comprehension** `[1 for x in X if x % 2]` is faster in Python 3 than Python 2 and its faster almost entirely because `x % 2` is faster.  The answer to 3. is yes.

Comment: @U10-Forward, which question is this a duplicate of?  thx

Comment: This is not a duplicate of list comprehension with and without `[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dealing with your original question, the speed differences observed have nothing to do with `len`, or `sum`, and everything to do with the fact that the comprehension itself is faster to evaluate in Python 3 than Python 2.

In particular it is faster because Python 3 is far more efficient at evaluating `%`

```
$ python3.7 -m timeit -s 'X = list(range(1000))' 'for x in X: x % 2'
10000 loops, best of 5: 23.9 usec per loop

$ python2.7 -m timeit -s 'X = list(range(1000))' 'for x in X: x % 2'
10000 loops, best of 3: 32.3 usec per loop
```

Next you remove the `%` and ask, why is `sum` slower in python 3, and again it has less to do with `sum` and more to do with the fact that generators are simply slower in Python 3 than Python 2

```
$ python2.7 -m timeit -s 'X = list(range(1000))' 'for x in (1 for y in X): pass'
10000 loops, best of 3: 30.6 usec per loop

$ python3.7 -m timeit -s 'X = list(range(1000))' 'for x in (1 for y in X): pass'
10000 loops, best of 5: 33.4 usec per loop
```

(Although I observe a much smaller difference in speed

Comment: FYI- I'm getting 35 and 42 usec for the generator for-loops from your example.

Comment: @user650654 hardware differences